# Prove whether or not there exists $N$ that satisfies following.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multivalued-functions

Prove whether or not there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for all $\epsilon\gt0,$ $\vert f^{(n)}(x_k)-f^{(n)}(x_1)\vert<\epsilon$ if $n\gt N$. Function $f$ is defined as follows.

For positive integer $k$, define $\pmb f:\mathbb R^k\rightarrow\mathbb R^k ,\pmb f(x_1,x_2,...,x_k)=(f(x_1),f(x_2),...,f(x_k))$, where
$x_1\le x_2\le...\le x_k$ and $$f(x_j)=(0.2+0.1\ln x_j)x_j+\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i\ne j}(0.2+0.1\ln x_i)x_i$$
for each $j\in\{1,2,...,k\}$.
Denote $f^{(2)}(x_i)=f(f(x_i))$ and $f^{(n)}(x_i)=f(f^{(n-1)}(x_i))$ for positive integer $n$.

This problem has bothered me for a long time. Is there a way to solve the problem? Or do I need additional conditions? What ideas do I need to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that the condition is satisfied? Or do you mean there is $N$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ the condition is satisfied? If it's the latter, it basically means $f^{(n)}(x_k)=f^{(n)}(x_1)$ for all $n>N$.

Comment: @MengchunZhang Thank you for your help. I mean the latter one. That is, as you said, $\lim_{n\to \infty}f^{(n)}(x_k)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f^{(n)}(x_1)$ for all real number $x_i$ where $i=1,2,3,...,k\lt \infty$